# How to use proxy in terminal?

Tags: macos, curl, proxy

If I unset http_proxy, curl works just fine. But if I

> export http_proxy= “127.0.0.1:10010”

The port is of socks5 and is found in the network setting of my MacBook. Then whatever address I curl, the following error occurs.

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server.

Also, I’m confused about how it works.

Comment: Please, type exactly how you set the proxy variable in code blocks : indent with 4 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it that this is a SOCKS5 proxy, rather than a plain HTTP proxy:

```
export http_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:10010"
#                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the "proxy protocol prefixes" section of the [`curl` man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).